# SQL command in VBA column limitation

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

Is there a limitation of how many columns can be brought over in one `sqlcommand` in VBA code? My code is quite long but is used to ensure that I am pulling from the right database at all times. The `m2mdata02` will be replaced with code `CatalogM2M` upon a user's selection in the database. The total number of columns to bring over is 23 columns from 7 tables.

```
Sqlcommand = “select left(m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.fjobno,5) as job, m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.fjobno, m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.fpartno, m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.fstatus, m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.fact_rel, m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.fddue_date, m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.fprodcl, m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.frel_dt, m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.frouting, m2mdata02.dbo.inmastx.fpartno, m2mdata02.dbo.inmastx.fdescript, m2mdata02.dbo.inmastx.fprice, m2mdata02.dbo.somast.fsono, m2mdata02.dbo.somast.fcompany, m2mdata02.dbo.somast.fcustpono, m2mdata02.dbo.aritem.fcinvoice, m2mdata02.dbo.aritem.fprice, m2mdata02.dbo.aritem.fcsono, m2mdata02.dbo.armast.fcinvoice, m2mdata02.dbo.armast.finvdate, m2mdata02.dbo.shmast.fshipdate, m2mdata02.dbo.shmast.fshipno, m2mdata02.dbo.shmast.fcsono
from m2mdata02.dbo.jomast
left join m2mdata02.dbo.inmastx on m2mdata02.dbo.inmastx.fpartno = m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.fpartno
left join m2mdata02.dbo.somast on m2mdata02.dbo.somast.fsono = m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.fsono 
left join m2mdata02.dbo.aritem on m2mdata02.dbo.aritem.FCSONO = m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.fsono
left join m2mdata02.dbo.armast on m2mdata02.dbo.armast.fcinvoice = m2mdata02.dbo.aritem.fcinvoice
left join m2mdata02.dbo.shmast on m2mdata02.dbo.shmast.fcsono = m2mdata02.dbo.somast.fsono
where m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.fprodcl = 'FG11' order by m2mdata02.dbo.jomast.fjobno”
```

Comment: The maximum number of columns per `SELECT` in SQL Server is 4096. I doubt there is a practical limitation in VBA.

Comment: Are you asking because you’re having a problem?

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/string-data-type), the character limit of `String` type in VBA is approximately two billion (2^31) Unicode characters. Your SQL query is no where near that limitation. And if using ADO to connect Excel VBA to database, the server engine here being SQL Server decides column limitation and 23 is again no where near [maximum capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

However, consider using table aliases to cut down on characters, avoid repeating triple period identifiers, and overall improve readability even maintainability as you can adjust table reference easier for each user selection.

```sql
select left(j.fjobno,5) as job
       , j.fjobno
       , j.fpartno
       , j.fstatus
       , j.fact_rel
       , j.fddue_date
       , j.fprodcl
       , j.frel_dt
       , j.frouting
       , i.fpartno
       , i.fdescript
       , i.fprice
       , so.fsono
       , so.fcompany
       , so.fcustpono
       , ari.fcinvoice
       , ari.fprice
       , ari.fcsono
       , arm..fcinvoice
       , arm..finvdate
       , sh.fshipdate
       , sh.fshipno
       , sh.fcsono 
       
from m2mdata02.dbo.jomast j
left join m2mdata02.dbo.inmastx i on i.fpartno = j.fpartno 
left join m2mdata02.dbo.somast so on so.fsono = j.fsono 
left join m2mdata02.dbo.aritem ari on ari.FCSONO = j.fsono 
left join m2mdata02.dbo.armast arm on arm..fcinvoice = ari.fcinvoice 
left join m2mdata02.dbo.shmast sh on sh.fcsono = so.fsono 
where j.fprodcl = 'FG11' 
order by j.fjobno
```

---

By the way, for very long queries, avoid the need to build string in VBA with line concatenation and double quotes, and read directly from a formatted SQL text file:

```vb
Dim strSQL As String

' READ SQL QUERY FROM FILE
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      strSQL = .OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\my\SQL\Query.sql", 1).readall
End With

' REPLACE DB IN STRING
strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "m2mdata02", "someotherdb")
```

Comment: Excellent points. I would consider creating a View.  Similar to your text file approach, I will store queries in textboxes on a dedicated userform. This allows me to access them like `m2mdata02Query = QueryForm.M2mdata02.Value`.  Using a [SQL Formatter](https://sqlformat.org/) also greatly improves the readability.

Comment: How would I set the database to a dynamic one? I am calling a public called "CatalogM2M" that is set based on a user's input. The user will select a mode that will direct the rest of my SQL to a specific database.

Comment: Did you see the `Replace` line in bottom VBA code block? Have the user input replace `"someotherdb"`.

Comment: I am using the line in my code block but want to reference my established catalogm2m dim as the database name. The user will not have knowledge of the correct database to reference. I have tried a couple things that did not work yet.

Comment: How do I make "m2mdata01" in this sql code a dynamic field. '''sqlcommand = Replace(sqlcommand, "m2mdata02", "m2mdata01")'''

Comment: Why doesn't that work assuming both tables have exact underlying schema? As seen `Replace` does change the data sources in SQL query: https://rextester.com/DYA62584. What do you mean *dynamic*? Changing fields in `SELECT`? Tables in `JOIN`? Please ask a *new* question with fuller details of your VBA needs.